# Need a second drop down box that has options depending on first drop down box selection

Tags: php

I have a drop down box select element that shows all U.S. states.

```html
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select the state</option>
  <?php foreach ($states as $state) : ?>

  <option value=<?php echo $state[ 'state'] ?>>
    <?php echo $state[ 'state'] ?>
  </option>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Naturally, I would like to have a second drop down box that would show the all the cities in the state that the user has selected.  How would I write a php script to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I can't comment until I've 50 reputation, so...sorry.

You can't do it only with PHP (remember, it runs on server side).

You'll have to do it using AJAX (I think that's what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in PHP. You need to use some client-side language, like java script. To do it easier, you could use jQuery, which is a java script library.